# Sequelize updating nested associations

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have an instance where I have **Users** and **Roles**. I have the following:

```
  var User = sequelize.define("Users", {
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
  });

  var Role = sequelize.define("Role", {
    role: DataTypes.STRING
  });

  var UsersRole = sequelize.define("UsersRole");

  User.belongsToMany(Role, {through: UsersRole});
```

Which creates a **UsersRoles** table in the DB for me with a UserId and RoleId column. This is all working fine, but now I want to be able to update a users role, I can't work out quite how to do this! I've tried the following with no luck so far:

```
models.Users.findAll({
    where: { id: req.params.id },
    include: [{ all: true }]
}).then(function(dbUser){
    dbUser[0].Roles[0].updateAttributes({
            RoleId: req.body.role,
        },
        {
            where: { UserId : req.params.id }
        }
    ).then(function (result) {...
```

In summary, all I want to do is be able to change a users role, so update the '**UsersRoles**' table and change the **RoleId** for a given **UserId**. I can't quite seem to figure out how to get to the **UsersRoles** table via any sequelize syntax!

I could write some raw SQL but that doesn't feel right?

**EDIT**

I just want to update a users role, if the table has:

```
| UserId | RoleId |
-------------------
|    1   |    1   |
```

I would like to be able to change it to:

```
| UserId | RoleId |
-------------------
|    1   |    2   |
```

but I can't quite figure out the code to do this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to interact with the join table directly - You can simply do

```
user.setRoles([newRole]);
```

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/belongs-to-many/#setassociationsnewassociations-options-promise

Notice that I'm passing an array, since users can have many roles - `set` removes all currently assigned roles. If you want to add a new role and keep the existing, use

```
user.addRole(newRole);
```

Comment: A couple of side-note: If you only need one user, use `findOne` or `findById` instead. Also, no need to `include: all` if you aren't going to use them

Answer (score 0):

you are updating `RoleId` but you have not defined it. If you don't define a primary key on a table the by default Sequelize defines a primary key by name if `id`, so you should do `id: req.body.role`.

Comment: Actually 'RoleId' gets created in the table as part of the association and this is the one I do want to update, sequelize created the table for me and there is no 'id' column

Comment: Another way of updating the role is like this  `dbUser[0].Roles[0].RoleId = req.body.role;  dbUser[0].Roles[0].save();` . Also why do you need the second where condiion first where condition will take care of filtering the user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried this and it still isn't working, I'm concerned that I'm trying to hack this a bit and actually there is a 'sequelize' way of doing this I should be trying instead?

Comment: Apologies, I don't think I've explained this well enough...its not the Role I want to update, is the UserRoles table, so which user is associated to which Role.